# Может ли модель работать с массивом _POST и записывать данные в сессию?

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

В модели пользователя я описываю метод регистрации. Могу ли я из этого метода напрямую взаимодействовать с массивом $_POST`, и при удачной регистрации записать данные в сессию?

Или же мне нужно в контроллере передать в метод регистрации данные формы , и получив результат выполнения регистрации записать данные в сессию?

И еще вопрос: кто должен заниматься валидацией данных - модель или контроллер?
Я сделал валидацию данных в сеттерах модели, т.е. перед тем как записать какое то свойство пользователя, будь то имя или email, в соответствующем сеттере данные сначала проходят проверку. Это приемлемо?

Comment: Очень рекомендую почитать https://habr.com/post/321050/ и половина вопросов пропадёт сама собой.

Comment: Вообще чистая `MVC` вызывает много вопросов в плане что где должно находиться, но как базис конечно стоит использовать. а теперь по вашим вопросам: Может ли модель работать с `post` - нет. с куками - нет. По факту модель это только набор функций, задача которых `получить` несколько данных, обработать, и выдать ответ, поэтому `post` массив передаем как параметр. а присвоение куков - это задача контроллера. Валидацей заниматься будет модель. Использовать в сеттере - нет, вы общаетесь с моделью только через ее функции, там и проверка, а не конкретно с переменными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему нельзя в модели? Модель это библиотека методов. Опишите в ней этот метод и потом вызывайте его в контроллере через объект модели.
В сессию лучше конечно записать после удачной регистрации. Сделайте это в контроллере, можно также куки создать.
Метод валидация опять таки описывается в модели, а вызывается в контроллере.